# NSObject (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios6, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I am using Leaves sample code from GitHub to display pdf file when UIButton is pressed in the detailviewcontroller of the collectionviewcontroller.

Difference is that Leaves project is using Tableviewcontroller but i m using collection view controller with the storyboard segue. In detailviewcontroller have a uibutton which displays pdf file when it is pressed. But when pressing that uibutton it is giving error

App is crashing and in the crashing log it says **NSObject doesnotrecognizeselector** and when app crashes it gives error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: [LeavesCache setDataSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

nsobject is LeavesCache and selector is the uibutton which i m pressing to display pdf file

This is the coding in the detailviewcontroller for uibutton to display pdf file

```
 - (IBAction)ReadAction:(id)sender { [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];} 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 { 
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) { 

    // Get destination view 

PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController]; 

NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag]; 

[pdfviewController setSelectedButton:tagIndex]; } }
```

Comment: So, does your LeavesCache class have a method named setDataSource?

Comment: everthing is same as it is in leaves project. As per leaves project Leaves view has this method setDataSource

Comment: What the error message is telling you is that the LeavesCache class does not have a method named `setDataSource:`.  Your above comment tends to indicate (as much as I can understand it) that you don't choose to believe this, but it's true.

Answer (score 1):

dataSource may be, in original project, the delegate of a UITableView implementinh the delegate methods declared in: UITableViewDataSource.

Are You sure that you try to set a dataSource to a class that has that property? In original project they may have a UITableViewController or UITableView (that has a property dataSource to be set) and you may use other class that doesn't...

as  "Hot Licks" is trying to tell you, in his comments, the error you are getting is just because you are trying to set a delegate  in a class that is not a UITableView and hasn't got that property. (and you may have done this in IBuilder too)

Comment: leavesview has both datasource and delegate protocol.@protocol LeavesViewDataSource;@protocol LeavesViewDelegate;@property (nonatomic) id<LeavesViewDataSource> dataSource;@property (nonatomic) id<LeavesViewDelegate> delegate;@protocol LeavesViewDataSource <NSObject>
- (NSUInteger) numberOfPagesInLeavesView:(LeavesView*)leavesView;
- (void) renderPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx;@end.LeavesCache has @protocol LeavesViewDataSource;@property (assign)id<LeavesViewDataSource> dataSource;PDFViewController will display pdf file when uibutton on detailviewcontroller is pressed

Comment: but what about class "LeavesCache"? that's the class that give the error